# (node:13040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
case 'mute':
            if(!message.member.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send(noperms);
            const reasonMute = args.slice(3).join(" ");
            const muteDuration = args[2];
            if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Nu ai specificat o persoana!');
            if(!muteDuration) return message.channel.send('Nu ai specificat durata sanctionarii!');
            if(!reasonMute) return message.channel.send('Nu ai specificat motivul sanctiunii!');
            var membermuted = message.guild.member(message.mentions.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]));
            guild.roles.create({data: {name: 'Muted', color: 'GRAY'}})
            let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(mutedRole => mutedRlole.name === "Muted");
            const channels = message.guild.channels;
            channels.forEach(f => {f.overwritePermissions([{id: mutedRole.id,deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'SPEAK'],},]);
            membermuted.roles.add(mutedRole.id);
            const muteembed555 = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`output: discord.js mute var1 var2 var3`).setColor('RED');
            message.channel.send(muteembed555);
            setTimeout(function() {
                membermuted.roles.remove(mutedRole.id);
            }, ms(muteDuration));
        });
        break;
```

error: (node:13040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Hey Alexander, could you please elaborate where the exception is thrown and explain your code a bit more? Posting only code and an error message is not helpfull.

Comment: add me on discord: Alexannder#0877

error: https://hastebin.com/ivitekiqoh.sql
what my code does: when .mute <name> <time> <reason> creates muted role and give to name then unmute name after time

Comment: i got the answear! please close the qustion

Comment: if you got an answer to your question please be so kind and post it here so later somebody else can also Benefit from it